# Using Python to plot flight data over portion of US?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, plot

**Question**

I have a dataset in Python that tracks the flightpath of an object. I know the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude of the flightpath. The flightpath is entirely over the Montana.

Is there a way to plot the flight path coordinates over the relevant portion of a map of the US?

**Example code and desired output**

For simplicity, suppose that my flightpath is a "straight" line that starts at `lat_start=46`, `lon_start=-109` and ends at `lat_end=46.5`,`lon_end=-110`. The duration of the flight is 1 hour and the object has constant upward velocity of 1 m/s during the flight.

It would be really cool to have a 3D scatterplot showing the flight path in 3D space with the map shown on the bottom surface of the scatterplot, beneath the lat-lon-altitude points.

But a 2D scatterplot with just the lat-lon coordinates shown on top of a map would also be great.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# starting, ending latitudes and longitudes
lat_start=46
lat_end=46.5
lon_start=-109
lon_end=-110

upward_vel=1 #m/s
flight_time=3600 #s

# example flight path data
lat=np.linspace(lat_start,lat_end,100)
lon=np.linspace(lon_start,lon_end,100)
alt=np.linspace(0,upward_vel*flight_time,100)

# 3d scatterplot showing flight path
# how to show map on bottom plane of plot?
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(lat,lon,alt,marker='.',s=2)
ax.set_xlabel('lat')
ax.set_ylabel('lon')
ax.set_zlabel('Altitude (m/s)')
plt.xlim(45.5,47)
plt.ylim(-111,-108)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output from the example code above. I would like to display the map on the bottom surface of the 3D plot, or if that's no possible, simply overlay my flight data on a 2D plot.

[image]

Comment: It is a pure Matplotlib problem

Comment: If we ignore shapefiles, coordinates, coordinate systems, and maps, then I would have no option but to agree that it is a pure matplotlib problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I was able to manage using geopandas, using shapefiles from [spacialsci.com](http://www.spatialsci.com/index.php/sID/6d20ebde/fuseaction/data.view.html). It's not exactly what I was hoping for, I would love to find a way to make it interactive (pan-able) and show more terrain features.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
 
# starting, ending latitudes and longitudes
lat_start=46;
lat_end=46.5;
lon_start=-109;
lon_end=-110;

# example flight path data
lat=np.linspace(lat_start,lat_end,100);
lon=np.linspace(lon_start,lon_end,100);
fp = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(lon,lat)]
fpgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=fp).set_crs("EPSG:4269")


counties = gpd.read_file('MT_Counties/county.shp').to_crs("EPSG:4269")
highways = gpd.read_file('MT_highways/rd16.shp').to_crs("EPSG:4269")
cities = gpd.read_file('MT_cities/towns.shp').to_crs("EPSG:4269")
ax = counties.boundary.plot(linewidth=0.5)
highways.plot(ax=ax,color='grey',linewidth=0.5)
cities[cities['POP_2000']>100].plot(ax=ax,markersize=2)
fpgdf.plot(ax=ax,markersize=3)

for idx,dat in cities[cities['POP_2000']>100].iterrows():
    ax.annotate(dat['NAME'],(dat['LON'],dat['LAT']),fontsize=8)

ax.set_xlim(-111,-107)
ax.set_ylim(45.5,47)
```

[image]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/ ?

Comment: That looks great! I'll try using plotly

Comment: Few Other Options :

ipyLeaflet:    https://emmanuelboidot.github.io/pyLeaflet/

and HERE Map Widget for Jupyter: https://github.com/heremaps/here-map-widget-for-jupyter